# state of the art technology questions

Tags: discussion

I want to make a question about state-of-the-art mirror technology and beam divergence for space and astronomy applications. Since engineering questions seem to be, if not considered off-topic, at least frowned upon by the moderation (beats me why).

So i'm wondering what would be the best way to ask that question that would be deemed acceptable. Since the question has relationship with astronomy and space applications, i'm wondering if i can rely on that for making the question on-topic

link to the question in main: [Mirrors and light beam divergence technology limits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53048/955)

Comment: I don't have the time to write a full answer, but you may want to see http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/experimental-technology-questions-on-topic. Also, it may help if you give an overview of the question in your meta post :)

Comment: Well, really the recommended way to go about it is to just post the question on the main site, and if it gets closed as off topic, you have your answer. That being said, this is a small site and I don't think anyone cares if we ignore that particular rule sometimes. Either way, like Manishearth said, it would be good to have the actual question to serve as an example. Based on what you're saying here I could see it going either way.

Comment: Btw, not all engineering qs are frowned upon. The type of engineering q which are (a) "Calculate/optimize this" type problems or (b) about something which really isn't known to physicists -- those are frowned upon. Experimental tech is (probably) OK because it _is_ known to a lot of experimental physicists.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/should-how-do-i-solve-this-experimental-problem-questions-be-on-topic?